# live streaming web cam video using HTML 5 so that other users can view it

Tags: html, streaming, real-time, webcam

The question differs from other similar question because what I want is one user should stream one's video to a server and other users accessing the same server for that specific user should be able to see the same streamed video. Think of a situation where a teacher is teaching online (real time) and multiple students are viewing it.
I can access the web cam using HTML5 and also see my own video. Now I want server and client side support to stream it. I can use either Flash / HTML 5 if there is a way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 Web sockets.. THis may help you
    http://badankles.com/?p=209

Answer (score 3):

Check out [binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) which is a framework for sending binary data back and forward between (JavaScript) client and ([node](http://nodejs.org/)) server using websockets.

Audio / video webchat over websockets is listed as one of the capabilities of the library.